# tee command not working

Tags: bash, shell, tee

I am running a script which is using `tee` command to log the output to screen and also to a file. Script is as follows:

```
Script.sh:
count=1
while [ $count -le 10 ]
do
  echo "`date` : Function call, loopcount - $count" | tee -a logfile.log
  functioncall
  count=$( $count + 1 )
done
```

The fucntioncall() function is defined in the same script.

```
functioncall(){

<some processing>
cd $Location
<some processing>
}
```

When I run Script.sh, this script runs successfully, but only one entry is made in the logfile.log, for the first run, whereas in the output screen I can see that the loop is running for 10 times with correct loopcount incremented and displayed, but the entry in the logfile.log is not done.

When I comment line `cd $Location` in the script it behaves as desired, means both O/P and logfile.log show the correct loopcount.

Any idea why this undefined behavior is observed? Any fix/workaround is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Look for a `logfile.log` in `$Location`.

Comment: Thanks @Mat ! I'll got it during debugging using pushd and popd option, figured out the logical error

Comment: Also, did you mean `while [ $count -le 10 ]` ?

Comment: @anishsane: Thanks! for the input, I did mistake in the post, now corrected it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you change directory it is changed. Which means that tee will write to a new file.

Possible solutions:

- instead of `tee -a logfile.log` use `tee -a <absolute_path_to_current_directory>/logfile.log`
- move the whole `tee` outside the loop:

  ```
  while
  do
      stuff
  done | tee logfile.log # bonus - you don't need -a here
  ```
- return to initial location after `cd`. Which should be actually done with `pushd` and `popd`
- do not do `cd` in main shell. Do all processing in subshell:

  ```
  (cd $location;
      <some processing>)
  ```

I myself prefer the last one.

On the other hand (and that might be even better) - rewrite the processing to avoid `cd` at all.